# Relationship between an integer N and the number of bits n required to represent the integer

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I'm trying to understand the time complexity of the following code in terms of n.

Pseudocode for trial division:

[image: Pseudocode for trial division]

I understand that the time complexity of the algorithm is O(sqrt(N)). However, can someone explain how the person in the link below came up with O(e^(n/2)). In other words, what's the mathematical relationship between N and n? Thanks.

Time complexity explanation:

[image: Time complexity explanation]

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We ask that questions here be self-contained, so they can be understood without following any external links.   I've edited your post to put the images inline (I know you can't include more than one image, as a new user).  However, please don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). (continued)

Comment: Please transcribe text and mathematics -- note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) -- and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Is [this pdf](http://connellybarnes.com/documents/factoring.pdf) the source of the images?

Answer (score 2):

The integer $N$ takes $\log_2 N$ bits to write down.  Set $n = \log_2 N$.  Then $N = 2^n$, so $\sqrt{N} = 2^{n/2}$.

I'd guess they are using the natural logarithm (to base $e$), which is where they get $e$ instead of $2$.  That's a bit odd but I suppose it is valid.

See also [Complexity of multiplication](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52640/755) and [Precise runtime of the algorithm to find number of digits in an integer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37052/755).